# gdal_merge Sum/Agregation files into single output band

Tags: gdal, merge

I need to create a single tiff files from several others (each have the same extent and resolution) and the output file need to have a single band containing the aggregated/sum of the values in the separate files.

I was playing with gdal_merg, - in the the [gdal_merge](http://gdal.org/gdal_merge.html) documentation the definition include *"In areas of overlap, the last image will be copied over earlier ones."* wich is not what I need. I got somewhat over that by using the *-separate* parameter that give me a single file with multiple bands, each representing one of the source files.

Is there a python/command line way how I can sum these multiple bands programmatically? (similar to the Raster Calculator GUI in QGIS)

Or even better do it in a single step?

Thanks in advance.
g

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do in a single step with [**gdal_calc.py**](http://svn.osgeo.org/gdal/trunk/gdal/swig/python/scripts/gdal_calc.py). For instance:

```
# example 1 - add two files together
gdal_calc.py -A input1.tif -B input2.tif --outfile=result.tif --calc="A+B"
```

Comment: This is a bit of an old question, but is there a way to pass a list of a large number of tiff files to gdal_calc.py and sum them all?